# jQuery watermark throwing TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing my first jQuery and getting an `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.  The first part of the code that initially sets the watermark is fine.  However both the `blur` and `focus` functions throw an error when I try to access the `.val()` of the input field.  Any one know the reason why?

```
jQ(document).ready(function($) {
var $watermark = 'dd-MMM-yyyy';
var $calendarVal = $('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').val(); /* this works no problem */
if ($calendarVal == null || $calendarVal == '')
{
    alert('Inside null or empty conditional');
    $('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').val($watermark).addClass('watermark');  /* this works no problem */
}
$('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').blur(function($){
    var blurCalendarVal = $('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').val();  /* this line throws the error */
    if (blurCalendarVal == null || blurCalendarVal == '' || blurCalendarVal.length == 0)
    {
        alert('Inside blur function conditional');  /* Never make it here */
        $('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
    }
})
$('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').focus(function($){
    /*if ($(this).val() == watermark) This is commented out but this throws the error as well
    {
        $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
    }*/
    var $focusCalendarVal = $('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').val(); /* this line throws the error */
    var $watermarkDate = 'dd/MMM/yyyy';
    if ($focusCalendarVal == $watermarkDate)
    {
        alert('Inside focus function conditional');
        $('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').val('').removeClass('watermark');
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').blur(function($){
```

you are remapping `$` to be the `event` object passed into the handler. Use a different parameter name, like `e` or `event`.

```
$('#tabForm\\:opStartInputDate').blur(function(e){ // fixed
```

---

I assume your confusion stems from the opening line

```
jQ(document).ready(function($) {
```

The `jQuery().ready()` handler receives `jQuery` as its first argument, so using `$` here ensures that `$` is `jQuery` inside the `ready` handler. However, you have copied this incorrectly into your `event` handlers, which receive an `Event` object as their first argument. In the lines throwing errors, you are essentially calling `Event(...)` instead of `jQuery(...)`, hence the error `object is not a function.`

Comment: That was the problem!  Thank you for explaining it to me!